# ADT on Eclipse Juno can't detect my lenovo s920 in windows 8

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm try to develop an android app. 
But my eclipse can't detect my lenovo s920. 
What should i do.

Comment: What in the name of *sanity* are you asking? Eclipse Juno is ancient, but what does a Lenovo s920 have to do with android?

Comment: Have you install your usb driver's phone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your phone driver http://androidxda.com/download-lenovo-usb-drivers

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me, Just download the USB driver. Here is a page a googled "http://androidbreak.com/data/Driver.zip"

Answer (score 0):

Download the [MoboRobo](http://www.moborobo.com/) software and then install your system.It will work fine.This software is not only Lenova,it for all devices.